# JustMock Will ReturnsMany returns in sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, justmock

I am arranging call for a method in a unit test like below

```
container.Arrange(p=> p.doSomething(Arg.AnyString, Arg.AnyString)).ReturnsMany(1, 2);
```

Is 1 and 2 will be returned in sequence always or InSequence() chain is required?

Will ReturnsMany returns values in sequence or explicit InSequence is required?

Docs: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/justmock/api/overload_telerik_justmock_helpers_multiplereturnvaluechainhelper_returnsmany

Comment: What is your question about?

Comment: Knowing nothing about this, I can tell you that the docs you linked to say that it configures multiple calls to a method, so it seems you don't have to call anything else and it will set up the values to return in sequence

Answer (score 0):

To save a sequence, `InSequence()` method call is not required. To make sure you can see [the source code](https://github.com/telerik/JustMockLite/blob/master/Telerik.JustMock/Helpers/MultipleReturnValueChainHelper.cs):

```
private class ReturnsManyImpl<TReturn>
{
    internal int CurrentIndex;
    private readonly IList<TReturn> values;
    private readonly Action<ReturnsManyImpl<TReturn>> afterEndAction;

    public ReturnsManyImpl(IList<TReturn> values, Action<ReturnsManyImpl<TReturn>> afterEndAction)
    {
        this.afterEndAction = afterEndAction;
        this.values = values;
    }

    internal TReturn GetNext()
    {
        if (CurrentIndex >= values.Count)
            afterEndAction(this);

        return values[CurrentIndex++];
    }
}
```

But remember about `behavior` parameter, by default it is equal to `AfterLastValue.KeepReturningLastValue`.